# Printing elements from a tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
if select == '2':
    print('Displaying all employees\n')
    print('Employee names:\n')
    for records in record:
        print(record[0])
```

My 1st option works perfectly fine,
however my 2nd optiond doesn't print out the "enterName" from the list. How do I fix this? I tried to find answer but I couldn't find one specific enough.

Thanks for looking, and helping me :).

Also, another problem I have is that when trying to add more than one "new employee" it overwrites the first one, how can I work around this?

Comment: The second issue happens because every time you select "1" the list `record` is recreated. If you put it before the `while`, I think you can solve it.

Comment: And what it is the output?

Comment: Also, within the last loop you should `print(records)`. I'd recommend changing the name of the list to `records`, so you can then do `for record in records` and finally `print(record)`.

Comment: @gabra do you mean to put the records = [] before the while loop or "1" before? If I put "1" before then it won't be in the menu

Comment: @wndzyo put `record` before the `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

There are tow issues. The first is printing the employees. What are you doing is printing the full array and not the items of the `for` loop.

The second issue is that `record` is being recreated every time you select "1". You probably should put it before the `while` loop.

I also fixed the identation. I hope it is better now.

For example:

```
select=True
record=[]
while select:
    print ("""
Personnel Database 
    1. Add a new employee
    2. Display all employees
    3. Search for an employee
    4. View full-time employees
    5. View part-time employees
    6. View number of employee records in database
    7. Delete an employee from the database
    8. Exit
    Choose an option (1-7) or 8 to Exit
    """)
    select=input("What would you like to do? ")
    if select == "1":
        print("Add a new employee")
        enterName = input ("Enter employee name:")
        enterTitle = input ("Enter employee Job title:")
        enterRate = float (input ("Enter employee hourly rate:£"))
        enterService = float(input ("Enter number of years service:"))
        fulltime = input ("Is the employee full-time? Y/N:")
        if fulltime.capitalize == "Y":
            break
        elif fulltime == "N":
            break

        record.append((enterName, enterTitle, enterRate, enterService, fulltime))
        print ("The employee you have entered is:",record)

    if select == "2":
        print ("Displaying all employees")
        print ("Employee names:")
        for r in record:
           print(r[0])
```

Comment: It still seems to overwrite it, because when I enter two employees and then go to put in "  2" it only shows the latest employee that I have added. Also, thank you for helping me out, it is highly appreicated :)

Comment: @wndzyo I forgot to remove the `record` inside the `while` loop. I edited the answer.

Comment: thanks very much :). I also noticed another problem which I'm not too sure how to fix (sorry, my python knowledge is limited and i am learning!) but when I add some employees then press "2" to display the employees, it also adds the one I last input to the list again, how do I fix that?

Comment: There was a problem with indentation. I think I fixed it now.

Comment: thank you bro! It's the small things I mess up on, but by people like you helping I can learn :)!